# How to model dynamic relationships in panel data when units exhibit heterogeneous variance

Tags: multivariate-analysis, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, dynamic-regression

So I'm taking a look at a dataset of about 200 individuals, each with a number of variables measured 50 times longitudinally. A lot of these variables are subjective, and scored on a scale of 0-100, which 'seems' to have created large differences in scale usage - differences that are no doubt normally there with a 0-10 scale but are probably emphasised now.  Typically for this sort of data I would set up a structural equation with a measurement model relating the observed variables to latent scores, a dynamic model (auto / cross regressions, error terms with covariance) relating the latent processes over time, and a random intercept term accounting for heterogeneous levels of the process.  I want to estimate the dynamic parameters which characterise the processes, but am unsure how to best account for the large differences in variability of the processes in this case.  I could estimate variance parameters at the individual level, but expect this to heavily overfit.  Can anyone suggest how to do this in a structural equation context, or another approach that may work better?